# Decoding QRCode with zxing. Java

Tags: java, decode, qr-code, zxing

I generated a QRCode using zxing library.

```
    QRCode qrcode = QRCode.from("Encoding string").withSize(17,17).to(ImageType.PNG);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(output.toString()).withSize(10, 10).to(ImageType.PNG).stream();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\QR_Code.JPG"));
    fout.write(out.toByteArray());
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();
```

It works fine but now I want to decode generated QRCode. Is it possible to decode QRCode from an image with zxing? If so, can you give me a hint how to do it because I haven't found appropriate class or method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks good: http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-qr-code/

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

- You'll need an instance of `QRCodeReader` to decode qrcode data from a `BinaryBitmap`
- You need to instanciate a `HybridBinarizer` and pass it as a constructor argument to create your `BinaryBitmap`
- The `HybridBinarizer` needs an instance of `LuminanceSource`
- Take a look at `BufferedImageLuminanceSource`

Here is an example that would decode data from a buffered image:

```
public static String qrDecodeFromImage(BufferedImage img) {
        if(img!=null) {
            LuminanceSource bfImgLuminanceSource = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(img);
            BinaryBitmap binaryBmp = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(bfImgLuminanceSource));
            QRCodeReader qrReader = new QRCodeReader();
            Result result;
            try {
                result = qrReader.decode(binaryBmp);
                return result.getText();
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {} catch (ChecksumException e) {} catch (FormatException e) {}
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the ZXing project included in your project(source, etc).

Then you can use all sorts of ZXing classes to performing decoding/encoding, etc:

Look into these classes: `BinaryBitmap`, `QRCodeReader`, `ParsedResult`, `ResultParser` and give this a try:

```
Bitmap b = ...;//TODO: create a bitmap from your source...
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new RGBLuminanceSource(b)));
Result result = null;
QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();
try {
    result = reader.decode(bitmap);
    ParsedResult parsedResult = ResultParser.parseResult(result);
    //TODO: use parsedResult
}
catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {

}
catch(Exception e) {

}
```